# Eigenvalue of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=P_3(\mathbb{R})$ and $T$ is a linear operator such that $T(f(x))=xf'(x)+f''(x)-f(2)$. 
Find the eigenvalues for $T$ and an ordered basis such that $[T]_B$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: What is $P_3$? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: so I know the standard basis of P3(R) is (1,x,x^2,x^3) and based on the transform, I know xf'(x) will be (0,1,2,3) f''(x) is (2,6,0,0) and -f(2) is (-2,0,0,0) but this leaves me with a 4x3. I'm also not 100% I'm right on that.

Comment: What is $P_3(\mathbb{R})$? Cubic polynomials with real coefficients?

Comment: If so, you're in a finite-dimensional space... write down $T$ as a matrix, and compute the eigendecomposition.

Comment: my main problem is writing down T as a matrix in the first place, I know how to do it from there. I should've made that more clear.

Comment: Compute $T(f)$ for each $f$ in your standard basis. The results will give you the matrix for $T$ (with respect to that standard basis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a finite-dimensional Hilbert space, a linear operator is uniquely determined by its action on a basis and can be represented as a matrix in that basis. In particular, if your basis is $\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$,

$$T(1) = 0 + 0 - 1 = (-1)1 + 0x + 0x^2 + 0x^3,$$
so
$$T(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3) = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}-1 & ? & ? &?\\0 & ? & ? &?\\0 & ? & ? &?\\0 & ? & ? &?\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\\d\end{array}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\x\\x^2\\x^3\end{array}\right].$$

Can you fill in the rest of the columns?

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it now.

Comment: It becomes an upper triangle matrix so the det[A] is just the product of the diagonal right?

Comment: I haven't checked that $T$ is triangular, but if that is indeed the case, then yes, the determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of the diagonal entries.